# Parsing a List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, list

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
[{"id":1,"value":"p1","num":2},{"id":2,"value":"p1","num":4},{"id":3,"value":"p2","num":4}]
```

I want to iterate this list by only having id and create a list based on first picking up p1 and then p2, if p1 is in multiple , then giving priority to the higher number

```
out = [2,1,3]
```

How do I do it in one loop?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the logic. You're trying to sort by "value", with ties broken by "num", and give "id" back?

Comment: I want to break the tie with the value and give id back based on that

Comment: @j1-lee sort by `(value, num)`, then select `id`.

Answer (score 2):

Well there's no way to do this in only one loop, since your sorting is custom. You have to at least sort it first.

```py
def sort_function(d):
    value_str, num = d['value'], d['num']

    # This assumes that 'p2' should sort before 'p12'
    value = int(value_str[1:])  # strips off the 'p' and treats the rest as a number
    return (value, -num)

out = [dct['id'] for dct in sorted(input_dictionary, key=sort_function)]
```

Comment: Should probably be `return (value, -num)` in `sort_function`, since the OP wanted ties to be broken in decreasing order of `'num'`.

Comment: Totally right! Thanks guys